# Are there any getter jQuerys CSS translation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

jQuery's cross browser support is amazing.
However I was wondering whether the following script will work in any browser or not.

```
$("#block1").css('background','blue');
$("#block2").css('backgroundColor', '#0000ff');
$("#block3").css('background-color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');

if ( $("#block1").css('background-color') == $("#block2").css('background-color') &&  
     $("#block1").css('background-color') == $("#block3").css('background-color') )
{
   alert ( 'same color : ' + $("#block1").css('background') );
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/oraje)

As you see these 3 different setter methods do exactly the same thing. Changing the background color to blue.

It seems that there are translations for the setter method of the `.css` method.

I was curios if there are any translations for the getter method as well.

Comment: It would be better if you can check that by yourself.

Comment: Yes buddy. why dont you check it by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some reason it didn't work on my google-chrome(3.0.195.27 - windows) but worked on firefox.
hope it helps.

**edit:**
further testing revealed interesting results.

a) it seems that chrome converts the #0000ff to rgb(0,0,255) but the same does not apply to "blue"

b) firefox will display very diferent results depending on the property you are asking for. Specificaly for the background-color property it converts the colors to the format rgb(0,0,255)

just watch:

[chrome, 'background' property http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/7223/chrome1.png](http://img237.imageshack.us/img237/7223/chrome1.png)
[chrome, 'background-color' property http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7383/chrome2.png](http://img43.imageshack.us/img43/7383/chrome2.png)
[chrome, 'backgroundColor' property http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/1127/chrome3.png](http://img98.imageshack.us/img98/1127/chrome3.png)
[firefox, 'background' property http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/2374/firefox1b.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/2374/firefox1b.png)
[firefox, 'background-color' property http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3706/firefox2h.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/3706/firefox2h.png)
[firefox, 'backgroundColor' property http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9139/firefox3.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/9139/firefox3.png)

feel free to [test](http://pastie.org/669776) it out yourself.

Comment: thx!
I guess the translations are only done by the browser not by jQuery.

Comment: from the other answers I think the conclusion would be that jQuery only does some translations (like the already mentioned opacity).
the only way to really know if the translation is done for a specific property is to test or check the source.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really have anything to do with jquery ... a browser's css support is completely independent of jQuery's ability to support a cross-browser API (which you are right, is amazing ;-) ).  I hate to say it, but the only way of finding out is to try that specific code snippet in the different browsers that you're targeting

Comment: It could be related to jQuery - what I think the OP is asking is 'Does Jquery do any translation of CSS attributes/values, based upon the host browser?'

Comment: to follow belugabob, yes, jQuery does check the browser first. This is evident when setting opacity. It will result i different CSS styles for FF, IE and such.

Comment: wow, honestly I wasn't aware that jquery did this transparent translation for css ... awesome :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `backgroundColor` instead of `background-color`, just as if you did it using standard JS - i.e. `element.style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';`.

Comment: jQuery handles this discrepency

Comment: Didn't know! Turns out that older versions didn't manage this well, so maybe depending on your version you might as well do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Where you set the CSS property is a browser problem.

jQuery "normalize" only where reading the property

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is open-source and although the code isn't very easy to read, with a little effort and by using Firebug to walk through the code you can find the information you are looking for. Let me help you with the jquery-1.3.2.

For setting a style look at line 1037. As you can see jQuery only has a special handling for IE opacity. It also uses a regular expression to convert the style name to a camel case notation. So, `background-color` will actually get translated to `backgroundColor`. See also the prop function (line 698). When setting a number to a css property and units haven't been defined, 'px' will be used. See the exclude method (line 612) for properties excluded from this pattern.

For reading a property see the curCSS function in line 781. Again opacity is special handled. Also, there is some rather complicated code for the handling of cascaded styles. See this [discussion](http://erik.eae.net/archives/2007/07/27/18.54.15/#comment-102291), which is actually referenced from jQuery's code. Again IE needs to be special handled.

There is also a subtle difference, when reading the style for `backgroundColor` and `background-color`. To understand what is happening, you can run the following code:

```
element = document.getElementById('block1');
alert(element.style['backgroundColor']);
alert(element.style['background-color']);
alert(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle( element, null ).getPropertyValue( 'background-color' ));
```

When reading, jQuery doesn't translate all styles to camel case. If `style[name]` is defined, it directly returns it. Otherwise it uses `getComputedStyle`. Things are more complicated for cascaded styles.

Comment: apparently background-color is not translated on all browsers. (see my post)

Comment: jQuery only translates the name of the property (converts it to Camel case) and not the value. It then depends on the browser on how to handle the value written and what to return when reading back.

Comment: if he translates the name of the property getting from background-color and backgroundColor should return the same value, right? and that didn't happen...

Comment: See my edited answer. There is no magical translation. Just walk through the code to understand what is happening.